# Dynamic search in mvvm view

Tags: search, mvvm, command

I'm creating a customer search screen in WPF, trying to follow the MVVM pattern.
My scenario is I have three possible search options at present:Customer surname; Customer Reference no; Customer with follow up due in x number days.

I have a grid with 3 rows, one for each search available. A radio button for each to identify which search user wants to perform and a button. I am going to add commands to my view model for each but in XAML how would I set correct command and pass correct parameter to the command? Only way I can think is 3 buttons and collapse the two non applicable???????? This sounds a sweaty hack....

Anyone point me to correct method?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just need 1 TextBox, 1 Button and a few [bounded RadioButtons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397556/how-to-bind-radiobuttons-to-an-enum).

Then use [MultiBinding on the Command's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108044/how-to-pass-parameters-to-command-using-multibinding) `CommandParameter` to pass both the text and the value of the choosen RadioButton (which are both binded to values in the ViewModel)