# How can I pass 2 parameters with CommandParameter to the command

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xaml

How can I pass 2 parameters with CommandParameter to the command

```
<Button Command="{Binding NavCommand}" CommandParameter="string1 and string2" >
```

Comment: That's not possible as I know

Comment: Is there any way to do this? To pass an array or something like this

Comment: An alternative is to use multibinding and a converter: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9108585/869621

Comment: `CommandParameter` is necessarily only ever one value. However, you can combine multiple values into a single object and pass that single object. If you need to _bind_ source properties to the parameter, then using `IMultiValueConverter` would be warranted. Otherwise, you can just construct the simple parameter object and pass it directly (you'll have to specify the `CommandParameter` value in a separate `Button.CommandParameter` element, instead of as a text attribute).