# How to pass Integer values to Command parameter MultiBinding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to pass integer values to command parameter like

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SapHasap.Views"

...

<Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                             Style="{StaticResource PopupButtons}"
                             Command="{Binding cmdNewEmployee}" >
<Button.CommandParameter>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiBindingConverter}">
        <sys:Int32>1</sys:Int32>
        <sys:Int32>3</sys:Int32>
    </MultiBinding>
</Button.CommandParameter>

...
```

but its false. How can I do something like that correctly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108044/how-to-pass-parameters-to-command-using-multibinding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

specify two Bindings, each with hard-coded Source

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiBindingConverter}">

   <Binding>
      <Binding.Source>
         <sys:Int32>1</sys:Int32>
      </Binding.Source>
   </Binding>

   <Binding>
      <Binding.Source>
         <sys:Int32>3</sys:Int32>
      </Binding.Source>
   </Binding>

</MultiBinding>
```